# Html.ActionLink with an area and parameters and html attribures

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I try to create such a this link with Html.ActionLink

```
<a class="page-link" href="@($"/administrator/Product/?page ={pageNumber} &pageSize =5")">@pageNumber</a>
```

```
        @Html.ActionLink($"{pageNumber}", "Index", "Product", new { Area = "administrator", pageNumber = $"{pageNumber}", pageSize = 5 })
```

I need my actionLink to have some parameter with an area an Html attribute.

I don't figure out what problem is.

And I came to this:

```
        @Html.ActionLink($"{pageNumber}", "Index", "Product", new { Area = "administrator", page = $"{pageNumber}",pageSize =5 }, new { })
```

it works correctly but it doesn't have html css class.

Answer (score 0):

finally I solved it this way:

```
        @Html.ActionLink($"{pageNumber}", "Index", "Product", new { Area = "administrator", page = $"{pageNumber}",pageSize =5 },htmlAttributes:new { @class="page-link"})
```

Is it a good way?